# ASP.NET MVC 4 Membership profile agasint mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

All i would like to do is add a profile for a user such that when in their account, they can update their profile.

I need to do this against mysql.

At this point, I'll even take a working example using MSSQLServer for starters.

I seek a single tutorial on how to do this, as two days of trying to piece this together has finally broken my will.  Anyone...?

Answer (score 0):

in web.config register a profile provider

```
<profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             <!--same connection string as the membership provider-->
             applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="string"/>
        <add name="LastName" type="string"/>
        <!--...or whatever profile properties you want/need-->
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

To set the profile properties

```
ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
profile["FirstName"] = "John";
profile["LastName"] = "Smith";
```

To read them

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
firstName = profile["FirstName"] as string,
lastName = profile["LastName"] as string,
```

Comment: When running the following:

ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(User.Identity.Name);
profile["FirstName"] = "James";

stepping through the code, User.Identity.Name returns the correct userid for the logged in user.  however, once the profile["FirstName"] = "James" line is executed, the following error is thrown:

Error: Unable to retrieve profile data from database.

Profile provider in web.config is configured as posted.

Comment: @John are you using the default membership provider?  That error is probably a database connection issue. Can you post the <membership> and <profile> sections of your web config?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if every thing in web.config is spelled correct, I had the same error and was a problem in the "connectionStringName" attribute.

I just found it downloading the MySQL.Web source and replacing the dll on my project, than I could see the real error, not just the generic exception.